# Why Oracle DATE type storing with time stamp and how to store only date

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

My Oracle table define with date type for one of the date column requestedDate.

While persisting, I am setting the value like below

```
.setRequestedDate(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now())))
```

And JPA entity defined like below,

```
@Column(name = "REQ_DT")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date requestedDate;
```

I am expecting value like "2022-05-12", but it gets stored like "2022-05-12 00:00:00.0"? I want to get rid of the timestamp when it gets inserted into the database.

Do I need to change the date definition in Oracle DB like creating view to truncate the timestamp?

Comment: Have you tried to map it to `LocalDate`? `java.util.Date` stores time info. Of course, whether that will work will depend on the driver

Comment: Do you mean `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: What *precisely* is the data type of your column?

Comment: DATE is DB column and java.util.Date is the one used in entity

Comment: The Oracle datatype `DATE` is equivalent to what in the SQL standard (and in JDBC) is called `TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Oracle `DATE` = SQL standard `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`

The `DATE` type in Oracle database in misnamed. As others noted, that type represents a **date with a time-of-day**. So values in a column of this type *always* have a time-of-day.

Furthermore, that type lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

You said:

> I want to get rid of the timestamp when it gets inserted into the database.

You cannot.

## JDBC

This Oracle `DATE` type is equivalent to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

While I do not use Oracle Database, I expect the following code works when using JDBC 4.2 or later.

### `LocalDateTime`

The Oracle type `DATE` matching in Java is [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

### `LocalDate`

Extract your date-only value as a [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
LocalDate ld = ldt.toLocalDate() ;
```

### Today

Note that a time zone is involved in determining the current date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone, “tomorrow” in Tokyo while simultaneously “yesterday” in Toledo.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;  // Or ZoneId.systemDefault()
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Write today’s date to Oracle `DATE` column.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = ld.atStartOfDay() ;  // Assign a time-of-day of 00:00:00 to the date-only `LocalDate` object, returning a `LocalDateTime` object.
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

Answer (score 4):

The Oracle `DATE` data type *always* includes a time component. If you don't specify one, then midnight is assumed. If you don't want the time portion to be *displayed*, then use the `to_char` function or some other native function in your programming language of choice in your application to control the display when the date is retrieved at runtime:

```
select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SY
----------
2022-11-24
```

Comment: I am looking for insert value without timestamp

Comment: @jcrshankar In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data type that is composed of 7 bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has all of those components so you cannot store a date without having a time component.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **insert** value without time component, then truncate it. You can't get rid of it because DATE datatype - in Oracle - always contains both date and time

Have a look at the following example:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, datum date);

Table created.
```

Altering the session, just to display full format while selecting DATE datatype values:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.
```

SYSDATE is a function that returns current date and time; as you can see, DATE_ONLY contains date component, while time is set to *midnight* (but it is still here):

```
SQL> select sysdate           value_with_date_and_time,
  2         trunc(sysdate)    date_only
  3  from dual;

VALUE_WITH_DATE_AND DATE_ONLY
------------------- -------------------
25.11.2022 07:11:21 25.11.2022 00:00:00
```

If you select such values into a table:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, datum)
  2    select 1, sysdate            from dual union all
  3    select 2, trunc(sysdate)     from dual;

2 rows created.
```

Select from it:

```
SQL> select * from test order by id;

        ID DATUM
---------- -------------------
         1 25.11.2022 07:11:48       --> both date and time
         2 25.11.2022 00:00:00       --> also date AND time, but time is set to midnight
```

If you want to *display* values without time, either alter session and set another format model, or use `to_char` function; once again: this will just **display** date only, but value - stored in the table - will still have both date and time:

```
SQL> select id, to_char(datum, 'dd.mm.yyyy') display_date
  2  from test order by id;

        ID DISPLAY_DA
---------- ----------
         1 25.11.2022
         2 25.11.2022

SQL>
```